# Ubuntu 16.04 - cpufrequtils scaling cores on demand?

Tags: 16.04, server, cpu, cpufreq

I would like to ask if it is possible to "scale" the number of cores used on a demand base as `cpufrequtils`does to frequency.

From BIOS I can set the number of cores to be used, in my case I use dual quad Xeon CPUs (X5365, E5450 mainly) and can choose to use between 2 to 4 cores per processor.

When idle, Ubuntu 16.04 scales the frequency from 3GHz down to 2GHz. Hence I would like to explore if its possible to "scale" so to say the numbers of cores used on a demand base as most of the CPUs where used for only 0.3%

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically the system does that already. Idle CPUs go into various levels of power saving c-states, the deeper the c-state the more power saved, but also the longer the time it takes to transition back to active. Newer processors can go into such a deep c-state that they can be considered "offline" in terms of power consumption. The idle framework within the kernel is very complicated, as it attempts to balance response time with energy savings.

For example:
I have an older i7 (4 cores, 2 threads per core, 8 CPUs), that only goes to the c6 state. Using turbostat, I get the following package powers in idle (and the computer is a server, where I have turned off many services, so it really is fairly idle):

4 cores online: 3.92 watts.
3 cores online: 3.91 watts.
2 cores online: 3.90 watts.
1 core online:  3.90 watts.

Comment: how do you install turbostat, tried sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.4.0-65 linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-65 but the packages could not be found. My kernel is 4.4.0-65-generic

Comment: I have install linux-tools-generic `sudo apt install linux-tools-generic` added `modprobe msr` but `sudo turbostat` is returning `WARNING: turbostat not found for kernel 4.4.0-65`

Comment: For unknown reasons, Ubuntu seems to introduce dependencies on turbostat that really are not needed. I don't have these issues because I compile turbostat myself from the mainline kernel code from kernel.org. I've helped many people by pointing them to a recently compiled version of turbostat on my web site, however I don't want to put a link here. (double u double u double u dot smythies dot com /~doug/linux/intel_pstate/energy/turbostat) My site if safe with no ads or java or anything, but you have no reason to believe me.

Comment: What you want is something like `sudo turbostat --debug sleep 10` (or much longer, for a better average power).

Comment: I think the Ubuntu package is `linux-tools-common`.

Comment: apart from monitoring, is there a tool that could do some tweaking apart from `cpufrequtils` please

Comment: I use the lowest level primitive commands for everything, never any higher level tool such as cpufrequtils or whatever.